# TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable in call function with numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
class RoastBot(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_size, conv_arr, rnn_arr):
        super(RoastBot, self).__init__()
        self.img_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_input_shape=[batch_size,None,None,3])
        self.text_input = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size,None])
        
        
        self.vocab = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        img = np.array(inputs['input_1'])
        print(img)
        text = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs['input_2'])
        x = self.img_input(img)
        x_prime = self.text_input(text)
        
        
        x = tf.keras.backend.flatten(x)
        x = tf.keras.backend.concatenate((x,x_prime))
        return self.vocab(x)
```

I'm currently having issues with model.fit, so I'm doing some debugging. My model takes as input an image and a sequence of ints as two separate inputs:

```
input_dict = {}
input_dict['input_1'] = img
input_dict['input_2'] = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([u'You look like '])
print(img.shape)
model(input_dict)
```

But in call(), the line `x = self.img_input(img)`, I get the TypeError that a tensor is not callable. I'm beginning to think that the Input layer just isn't callable when creating a custom model, am I wrong? What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I figured out the issue. It seems like my assumption was right, having the Input layer as the actual input seems to be the issue.

Instead, use whatever layer comes next, in my case, a Conv2D layer, and make sure to set `batch_input_shape` or `input_shape`